# Python ctypes combine two c_double arrays

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I have a Python program that needs to pass an array to a .dll that is expecting an array of c doubles. This is currently done by the following code, which is the fastest method of conversion I could find:

```
from array import array
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

python_array = np.array(some_python_array)
temp = array('d', python_array.astype('float'))
c_double_array = (c_double * len(temp)).from_buffer(temp)
```

...where 'np.array' is just there to show that in my case the python_array is a numpy array. Let's say I now have two c_double arrays: `c_double_array_a` and `c_double_array_b`, the issue I'm having is I would like to append `c_double_array_b` to `c_double_array_a` without reconverting to/from whatever python typically uses for arrays. Is there a way to do this with the ctypes library?

I've been reading through the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) but nothing seems to detail combining two c_type arrays *after* creation. It is very important in my program that they can be combined *after* creation, of course it would be trivial to just append `python_array_b` to `python_array_a` and then convert but that won't work in my case.

Thanks!

P.S. if anyone knows a way to speed up the conversion code that would also be greatly appreciated, it takes on the order of 150ms / million elements in the array and my program typically handles 1-10 million elements at a time.

Comment: numpy has built-in ctypes support.  Does `python_array.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))` work for you?  Keep all your data in numpy if you can and use this to pass it to a wrapped function.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen, I didn't know numpy had that functionality - that really cleans up some of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the construction of the `ctypes` arrays (for which [Mark's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687450/python-ctypes-combine-two-c-double-arrays#comment88392286_50687450) is surely relevant), the issue is that C arrays are not resizable: you can't `append` or `extend` them.  (There do exist [wrappers](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/475199-resizable-ctypes-arrays/) that provide these features, which may be useful references in constructing this.)  What you can do is make a new array of the size of the two existing arrays together and then `ctypes.memmove` them into it.  It might be possible to improve the performance by using `realloc`, but you'd have to go even lower than normal `ctypes` memory management to use it.